# Adding to the left and right sides of a dynamic array problem

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

So I'm trying to create a dynamic array in Java. For this question, there is one main array called store, that has a defined size. Within the store is a sort of pseudo-array that utilizes a chunk of store as a dynamic array. The left and right variables are indexes that serve as a head and tail for the dynamic array, respectively. This means that the value of left is the index where the dynamic array within store begins, and right is the end.

I've been trying to make addleft and addright methods for this, but I keep on getting out of bounds errors. However, I am not sure where I exactly went wrong with this.

```
    boolean add(int i, int x){
        if (i<0 || i>size) return false;
        if (i<size-i)
            addLeft(i,x);
        else
            addRight(i,x);
        return true;
    }//add
    void addLeft(int i, int x){
        size ++;
        left--;
        if(left == -1) {
            restore();
        }
        for(int j = left; j < left + i; j++) {
            store[j] = store[j+1];
        }
        store[left + 1 + i] = x;
        return;
    }//addLeft
    void addRight(int i, int x){
        size ++;
        right++;
        if(right == CAP+1) {
            restore();
        }
        for(int j = right; j > left + i; j--) {
            store[j] = store[j-1];
        }
        store[left + 1 + i] = x;
        return;
    }//addRight
```

The result i'm looking for is the integer inputted to be inserted at the index, and then the values to the left (for addleft) or to the right (for addright) to shift to their respective directions. The restore() method is used to expand the store array whenever one side of the dynamic array reaches an end.

Answer (score 1):

Did some Assumptions of the data types and replaced your functions with system.out commands.  I get out of bound exceptions in the for loops so I think your error is with your array called store `store[j] = store[j+1];` the line just out side your for loop scope is also out of bounds: `store[left + 1 + i] = x;`

This is an educated guess If you can post your entire code I'll run though it and hopefully can give a better answer!  Not sure what the variables size, left, right, store[] and CAP are.

update:

Was able to get the program to run after updating the addRight method.  Created a temp array from store with +1 size.  Store then clones temp.  here is my idea for how to approach the addRight method.

```
void addRight(int i, int x){
        size++;
        right++;
        if(right == CAP+1) {
            restore();
        }
        int[] temp;
        temp = new int[store.length+1];

        for(int j = 0; j <= store.length; j++) {
            if(j < i){
            temp[j] = store[j];
            }
            else if (j == i) {
            temp[j] = x;
            }
            else if( j > i)
            {
                temp[j] = store[j-1];
            }
        }
        store = new int [temp.length];
        for(int k = 0; k < temp.length; k++)
        {
            store[k] = temp[k];
        }
        return;
```

Comment: https://www19.zippyshare.com/v/S48aygWB/file.html, 

https://www19.zippyshare.com/v/gYUggd3X/file.html

second link is the abstract and has the constructor + variables

Comment: ty, i'll try this out